# Is is possible to know the position of a match in a subject string

Tags: php, regex

I have a file name where information has to be replaced. Here is a subject sample :

```
FileA-2014-11-01_K_1_A2_383.xxx
```

As many files are to be processed, this filename is first matched by a regex, say :

```
/[a-zA-Z]*-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_(\w)_(\d)_A2_(\d*)\.xxx$/
```

This regex will give me, using preg_match, the values to be replaced, here :

- K=>A
- 1=>2
- 383=>666

My first try was to naively use "str_replace", but it fails when patterns are repeated in the string : here i will get :

```
FileA-2024-22-02_A_2_A2_666.xxx
```

So the date is also modified by the str_replace (as it was told to do..)

So, i wonder if there is a way to know *where* is a given match in the string to have a clean replacement.
I'm now trying to revert the regex to be able to capture non-replacement blocks, and then insert replaced data. That regex would be :

```
/([a-zA-Z]*-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_)\w(_)\d(_A2_)\d*(\.xxx)$/
```

With that one, i'm able to keep non-replaced parts. I now have to find a kind of index to know the replacement position in the string. I guess I can achieve this way, but is seems somewhat complicated and error prone.
Given I only have the initial regex and the map for to=>from replacement, is there a way to do that in a better way?

[EDIT : solution]

```
<?php

$filename = "FileA-2014-11-01_K_1_A2_383.xxx";
$expected = "FileA-2014-11-01_A_2_A2_666.xxx";

$regex = "/[a-zA-Z]*-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_(\w)_(\d)_A2_(\d*)\.xxx$/";


global $replacements;

$replacements["K"] = "A";
$replacements["1"] = "2";
$replacements["383"] = "666";


$result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches){
    global $replacements;
    print_r($matches);
    // ended here. no way.
}, $filename);


if(strcmp($result,$expected)==0)
    echo "preg_replace_callback() : Yep\n";
else
    echo "preg_replace_callback() : Nop\n";


preg_match($regex, $filename, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

// remove useless global string match
array_shift($matches);

$result = $filename;
foreach($matches as $matchInfo){

    $match    = $matchInfo[0];
    $position = $matchInfo[1];

    $matchLength= strlen($match);

    $beforeReplacementPart = substr($result, 0, $position);
    $afterReplacementPart = substr($result, ($position + $matchLength));
    $result = $beforeReplacementPart . $replacements[$match] . $afterReplacementPart;

}


if(strcmp($result,$expected)==0)
    echo "preg_match() and substr game : Yep\n";
else
    echo "preg_match() and substr game : Nop\n";
```

Comment: The string you provided (the filename) does not match the first regex. The regex probably should start with `[a-zA-Z]*` to match any letter; now it matches lowercase letters, minus and uppercase A and Z. Even after fixing this thing it still doesn't match.

Comment: I just fixed it. Its just here for problem explanation and is not relevant itself. Anyway, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `regex` that matches that filename:

```
$re  = '/[a-zA-Z]*-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_(\w)_(\d)_A2_(\d*)\.xxx$/';
$str = 'FileA-2014-11-01_K_1_A2_383.xxx';
```

If you add `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` as the fourth parameter (`$flags`) to the call to [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), it will also return the offset of each captured string in the third parameter:

```
preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

A `print_r($matches)` will reveal:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FileA-2014-11-01_K_1_A2_383.xxx
            [1] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => K
            [1] => 17
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 19
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 383
            [1] => 24
        )
)
```

`$matches[0]` is the part that matched the entire `regex`. `$matches[1]` is the first capturing sub-expression, `$matches[2]` is the second and so on.

`$matches[1][0]` is the fragment from the input string that matched the first `regex` sub-expression `(\w)` and `$matches[1][1]` is the offset in the input string where it was found. The same for `$matches[N][0]` and `$matches[N][1]` for the `N`<sup>th</sup> sub-expression.

If you need to do a simple replacement then you don't need to bother about offsets but use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or, if the replacement expression is complex or dynamic, [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Using `preg_replace()` you need to capture the parts you want to keep:

```
$re  = '/([a-zA-Z]*-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_)\w_\d_A2_\d*(\.xxx)$/';
$str = 'FileA-2014-11-01_K_1_A2_383.xxx';

$new = preg_replace($re, '$1A_2_A2_666$2', $str);
echo($new."\n");
```

In the replacement string, `$1` and `$2` denote the sub-expressions from the `regex`. We marked them for capturing in order to re-use them in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

At least [preg_match_all()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) offers the option

> PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
>
>     If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned. Note that this changes the value of matches into an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset 0 and its string offset into subject at offset 1.

Comment: Nice one. with positions I can use substring game to replace exactly where I want

Comment: Yes, but it's rather likely you can achieve the same thing with preg_replace_callback() - just look it up in the manual ;-)

Comment: I haven't seen any reference to the replacement position in preg_replace_callback, as preg_match_all(...,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) can do

Comment: And I haven't seen any reason (yet) why you'd need the position when using preg_replace_callback ;-)

Comment: I tried but it does not help : the callback is called once with all the matches and there is no position information. So, to replace *only* the right occurence of "1" in my sample filename, i'm stuck. More, i have to use a global references for the from=>to map, which is really ugly (i may missed something about closure here, though).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible to use this in your case:

```
$str = strtr($str, array('_K_1_'=>'_A_2_', '_383.'=>'_666.'));
```

or

```
$str = str_replace('_K_1_A2_383.xxx', '_A_2_A2_666.xxx', $str);
```

So there is no more ambiguity and the replacement is fast.

Comment: thanks for reply. I can't use such pattern because of high diversity in filenames

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex.

```
([a-zA-Z]*-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?:-\d*)?_)\w_\d(_A2)_\d*(\.xxx)$
```

Then replace the match with

```
\1A_2\2_666\3
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aS7zX3/2)

```
$re = "~([a-zA-Z]*-\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}(?:-\\d*)?_)\\w_\\d(_A2)_\\d*(\\.xxx)$~m";
$str = "FileA-2014-11-01_K_1_A2_383.xxx";
$subst = "\1A_2\2_666\3";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$re = "/([a-zA-Z]+-\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}_)\\w+_\\d+(_A2_)\\d+(\\.xxx)$/m"; 
$str = "FileA-2014-11-01_K_1_A2_383.xxx"; 
$subst = "${1}A_2${2}666${3}"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
//=> FileA-2014-11-01_A_2_A2_666.xxx
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF7cO4/1)